# R select data through loop in Move object

Tags: r, timestamp, move

I am trying to use a loop to select the first and last dates of a Move dataset - per animal. I created the loop as follows, with MMunstacked as my Move object:

```
> ID <- c("AP002", "AP003", "AP004", "AP005", "AP006", "AP007")
for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
  print(ID[i])
  print(head(timestamps(MMunstacked$ID[i]), n=1))
  print(tail(timestamps(MMunstacked$ID[i]), n=1))
}
```

But it gives me the following warning:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function 'timestamps' for signature "NULL"
```

This is because

```
> MMunstacked$ID[i]
NULL
```

However

```
> ID[1] 
"AP002"
```

and both

```
> MMunstacked$"AP002" 
> MMunstacked$AP002
```

give me the wanted data.

But if I put it all together:

```
> MMunstacked$ID[1] 
NULL
```

It gives me again NULL, which is probably what happens in the loop. 
I don't have much experience with this object in R and can't seem to find the answer online.

I thought, maybe it's because of the class, but that doesn't seem to be the case. 
There must be a difference between the "AP002" when just typing MMunstacked$AP002 and when extracted from ID, but I can't figure out what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix addressing like that. The part after the `$` operator will not get evaluated and turned into the name as you want it to. You can use `[[` operator to achieve the desired effect.

```
ID <- c("A")
test <- list("A" = "result")
test[[ID[1]]]
```

This way what is in the double brackets gets evaluated first and then the test list gets called with a name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already thought it was probably going to be an easy solution :)